# How find and replace String with Java InputStream?

Tags: java

I got `InputStream` from URL but I need to replace or remove a string and write to file. I try to use extension of `FilterInputStream` to replace, but my file is still the same.

I not necessarily need to have `InputStream` -> `InputStream.replace()`
but `InputStream` -> `File` with string replace

```java
class ReplacingInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

    LinkedList<Integer> inQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> outQueue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    final byte[] search, replacement;

    protected ReplacingInputStream(InputStream in,
                                   byte[] search,
                                   byte[] replacement) {
        super(in);
        this.search = search;
        this.replacement = replacement;
    }

    private boolean isMatchFound() {
        Iterator<Integer> inIter = inQueue.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < search.length; i++)
            if (!inIter.hasNext() || search[i] != inIter.next())
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    private void readAhead() throws IOException {
        // Work up some look-ahead.
        while (inQueue.size() < search.length) {
            int next = super.read();
            inQueue.offer(next);
            if (next == -1)
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        // Next byte already determined.
        if (outQueue.isEmpty()) {
            readAhead();

            if (isMatchFound()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < search.length; i++)
                    inQueue.remove();

                for (byte b : replacement)
                    outQueue.offer((int) b);
            } else
                outQueue.add(inQueue.remove());
        }
        return outQueue.remove();
    }
}
```

```java
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

byte[] search = "\"https\"".getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] replacement = "".getBytes("UTF-8");

InputStream ris = new ReplacingInputStream(is, search, replacement);

Files.copy(ris, file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: How many bytes maximum in the inputstream?

Comment: this days 100 Ko

Comment: Use a `Reader`, not an `InputStream`. Your replacing class should extend ` FilteredReader`.

Comment: I can have more details

Comment: I think the problem is caused by not calling `isMatchFound()` in the right place. You only call it when `outQueue` is empty, so you're missing occasions when there in fact is a match. I could be wrong - it just seems likely from a casual look at the code. I would recomment going through it in a debugger.

Comment: By the way, it seems strange that your constructor is protected. Don't you want to be able to create an instance of it?

Comment: If the input is only 100kb, and considering you're scraping it from a website so you won't notice a few extra microseconds, why don't you just read the input to a String, make the replacement and use the resulting String.

Comment: I need to modify the content because the file in URL is an XML with a bad certificate, which I must modify to be able to convert it with jaxb

Answer (score 1):

Finally i use scanner

```java
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

            String search = "\"https\"";
            String replace = "";

            try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))) {
                while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                    writer.append(scanner.nextLine().replace(search,replace));
                    writer.newLine();
                }
            }
```